# How much commentary is permitted in answers?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950514/xoreax-incredibuild-alternatives/3950606#3950606) while approving suggested edits. [The suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3950606/3) changed 'girls' to 'assistants'. That's too minor really so I improved the answer by [removing the tangent](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3950606/4). OP has [restored the tangent](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3950606/5), which [I rolled back again](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3950606/6). Without getting into a further edit war, what is the appropriate course of action?

---

This is the tangent with the offensive portion:

> **We even hooked up the machines of the <s>girls</s> assistants in the office with
>   IB. First time those machines did something useful.** `:)` At evenings,
>   when just a few developers were left, you'd have 30 cores compiling
>   for you alone. The introduction of IB actually got me off the C++
>   newsgroups, where I used to hang out all day, while waiting for the
>   compiler. Others played pool, Quake, or twiddled their thumbs for half
>   the day. I guess buying those expensive licenses actually was a very
>   good deal for our employer back then.

Comment: Really? The simple use of the word "girls" is sexist now?

Comment: @Infinite Recursion: I'm pretty sure the simple act of using a gender word is not inherently sexist (or use of any other description = prejudiced). That being said, it took me more than a few rereads to get that implication given that the *only* change was a single word, and I have to admit that it is pretty sinister.

Comment: The edit here makes it clear as day. I think we all know the answer to the title now.

Comment: As a rule of thumb we should be as neutral as possible when interacting with other people, at least in a professional site like this, exception made for the chat.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion You should read the whole answer. Context matters. Using “girls” to mean “assistants” is sexist. But the answer related some historical facts where some of the people involved were unmarried women, so “girls” is factual, not sexist, in that context.

Comment: The entire paragraph is fluff and can be deleted.  In this case I agree that girls is a bit sexist in the context of the second sentence.  In other circumstances it isn't necessarily.

Comment: That's a definition of "girl" that you'll find a *lot* of disagreement with, @Gilles, even if it is in some dictionaries. When I hear the word "girl", the 49-year-old unmarried engineer down the aisle from me doesn't spring to mind. Instead, I see my pre-teen nieces, playing with their phones. When I hear it as the OP laid it out, I hear sexism and condescension all wrapped up a little package.

Comment: @Infinite Recursion: Sorry I'm really horrible with quotes, can you explain what that means?

Comment: @Gilles I am an unmarried woman, so by your definition it would be factual to refer to me as a "girl". I am 65 years old, with a doctorate in computer science, over 30 years working for computer manufacturers, and an inventor on half a dozen US patents. Would you use "boy" to refer to an unmarried man with similar background? If not, that use of "girl" is sexist.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion You're assuming that "first time those machines did anything useful" was because they were girls; it could be just because they were non-technical users. I'd give the benefit of the doubt on that.

Comment: @Patricia: then the next question is, are *all* of your machines doing something useful? (As a DCS you must have more than a few.)

Comment: @Jongware I can't claim the Apple II in my closet is doing anything useful right now, though has done useful things, such as running VisiCalc and a Pascal compiler, in the past.

Comment: "Girls" is appropriate in contexts where "boys" is appropriate.  It implies an age range and level of maturity.  For native English speakers, using "girls" to describe professionals *is* sexist.  I fully understand that many people here do not use English as their first language, so some leeway and understanding is appropriate, when such language is used in an otherwise appropriate context.  Which this isn't.

Comment: One option you overlooked: vote to close the question, since it is blatantly off-topic.  (It has since been closed.)  Whether that makes discussion about the answer moot or not is another matter ...

Comment: The use of any unnecessary, gender-qualifying descriptors is inappropriate in commentary like this. It doesn't matter if we personally are offended by it: the question we need to ask is whether it brings enough to the post to make it worth the risk of offending someone else. In this particular case, I don't think explicitly it did. Particularly since this particular case of "the girls" is reminiscent of a '50s mentality that many--I'd like to think all--of us are trying to put behind us. Thus even if it's not directly offensive, it could still bring strongly negative feelings to many people.

Comment: How is it known that the "girls" were assistants? Why couldn't they have been just standard workers? If anything that's changing something deemed to be sexist to a complete assumption that may also be deemed to be sexist.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I would personally love to be referred to as "boy", at least on those days when I'm feeling too old.

Comment: @BoltClock Note that in addition to implying that the girls' computers were doing something useful for the first time, the original quote also implies that developers and girls are disjoints subsets of “computer operators”.

Comment: @gilles: To use different words for womens on base whether married or not is having actually a sexist connotation in the western hemisphere.

Comment: #FirstWorldProblems. Don't you all think it's silly to argue over is the word girl sexist for not?

Comment: I'm a woman (with 20 years technical experience and postgraduate degrees in Information Technology and Computer Science) and I find "girls" used in that context sexist.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Not all female software engineers are unmarried :/

Comment: Um, I didn't say they were, @intracept, just the one down the aisle from me.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I was just wondering the relevance of mentioning the fact that she is unmarried then.  Does the fact that she is unmarried make her a better software engineer?  It just seemed to be reinforcing the stereotype of female software engineers being decidedly unfeminine.

Comment: Notice the comment I was responding to, @intracept.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta So noted.  Sorry, I just saw red when I read that part in your comment :)

Comment: I get it, @intracept. This is a... *difficult* thread, and topic.

Comment: why is it "too minor really"?  what's the problem with short edits?  this is a real point of confusion on SO.

Comment: @JoeBlow: There is the option to reject edits as "Too Minor". You can either reject or select improve. I chose to improve and remove the whole paragraph.

Comment: The English language is missing the female counterpart of "guy" which tends to describe any male beyond the age of "boy". "Gal" is the closest candidate but certainly doesn't sound right!

Comment: @Gilles Using "girls" for unmarried women is not factual, it is sexist. The correct term for unmarried women is "women".

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan It seems to me that "the boys at [place]" or "the boys down at [place]", referring to professional adults is a fairly common idiom.

Comment: It's way more sexist to assume they're all assistants because they're female than to call them "girls"... really should have just removed the part about the computers never doing anything useful up to then.

Comment: To the original question - it's pure fluff and inappropriate. On the question of "girls", it is sexist because how is the gender of the people using those computers even a little bit relevant? It's not.

Comment: IMO this issue is taken far too seriously. I get called "one of the tech boys" at my office and I could care less because the ladies of my office love us tech boys. Did the OP intend offense? If not, don't take offense where none is intended. Simple as that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The point here isn't really to express more or less subjective opinions whether or not the post was sexist... that was not what the question was about.

The question is about whether or not it is relevant to add 10 lines of "the story of my life" anecdotes at the end of an answer.

It is not. You should edit out such fluff. So your original edit was appropriate. But when the 100k rep user, who really should know better, started a rollback war, you should probably have flagged for diamond mod attention and let them settle the dispute, rather than to respond in the same manner.

Comment: As a side note, a post which contains possible sexism, irrelevant rants and also a rollback war started by the poster, most likely deserves a down vote.

Comment: I am absolutely distraught by the probably half a dozen downvotes I got through your comment. Since they made such a huge dent in my reputation (most of which, BTW, I amassed _after_ I essentially stopped answering a couple of years ago), this is clearly changing my mind on the whole subject of adding anecdotes to explain why I have certain opinions.

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that the actions of the post's author should factor in to a decision as to whether or not to downvote. The author's actions should be irrelevant. Vote based on content itself, not on the actions of the owner of that content.

Answer (score 23):

Since you guys (ha!) discussed this while I was cycling through France with one of my kids, here's a belated response from me:

1. I am German and learned English in school (east of [the Iron Curtain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Curtain), so this only amounts to 10% of what I learned), while being in the US twice for a couple of months (50%), on the net (30%), and while being abroad in the UK and elsewhere (10%). To me as a foreigner "*the girls from the office*" is a phrase that I must have heard often, because it seems to be a common phrase to me. It might well be that this is something from the 50s, but that doesn't change the fact that I must have learned that phrase in the 90s.
2. When I worked at the company I referred to, what I named "the office" was indeed populated with women only, while the developers were all men. This was a fantastic shop to work at with an incredibly good company climate. (Which is why I stayed there for almost a decade.) Among other things, the boss had someone cooking for us. Everyday. For free. I can distinctly remember one of the women from the office poking her nose into development calling "Boys, lunch is ready!" She is about my age. (It's a decade ago that I quit after working there for almost a decade.) There were a couple of developers my age, and a few older than me. Half of them were people between 20 and 30. Of course, when one of the developers got wind of lunch being ready before someone in the office did, he'd go to the office and call the "girls" for lunch. Nobody took offense, nobody felt belittled.
3. The "office" doing things like accounting, CRM and such stuff, it was sneered on by us developers – and they looked down their noses at us "mere technicians". However, that was all good-natured and fun. Nobody took offense, nobody felt belittled. In this small shop (25 people at the max) everybody valued everybody else's work, and everybody knew that their work was valued.
4. After having quit there about a decade ago, they still know me and invite me to their parties. I also have a beer with the boss about once or twice a year and I am still in contact with the above mentioned woman. (Her daughter turned her into a grandmother last year.) She's what Germans consider typical for Berliners (big-mouthed), and if she saw the remark the way I originally wrote it, she would first grin and then give me a retort that would make you gasp. (And then she'd laugh out loud. About me.)
5. Besides being a programmer, I have taught (mainly C++) for 20 years. I have tutored fellow students, taught apprentice programmers, CS students, newbie programmers and seasoned ones. One of the things I have learned is that students do not fall asleep and everybody remembers your classes – and their content! –, if you season complicated stuff with a few funny remarks. I guess doing this comes natural to me (and I am not above making people laugh at my cost). I do this at Stack Overflow and [at other Stack Exchange sites](https://superuser.com/revisions/373867/3) as well
6. I would like Stack Overflow to be a bit more relaxed (and re-allow some of the fun question of old). I know this goes against what the self-proclaimed meta-elite has wrought the site into. But I am a C++ developer: If I feel like I want some dry reading, I have plenty of it in [the C++ Standard](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf) (which is so dry that you can make dust clouds puff up from it just by looking at it intensively). Heck, just pointing newbies to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)'s C++ entry makes their toenails curl up in disgust about the formal language. OTOH, everybody C++ programmer who's read Scott Meyers or Andrei Alexandrescu loves them for the fact that they are so much fun to read.
7. The fact that a lot of the fun that used to be at Stack Overflow has been pushed off to meta and to the chat is one important factor why I rarely ever contribute to the site nowadays. Constantly ploughing through scores of silly newbie questions in order to give politically correct answers is not my idea of spending my rare free time.
8. When it comes to political correctness in speech, I'm on the fence. Yes, I know, oppression expresses in language. OTOH, it doesn't automatically end when you change your language – and politically correct language often is pale, bloodless, and boring. Humans, however, prefer colorful, vivid, and interesting language.

That's been my €0.02 about the issue. Do with it what you want. Should I run across a question I consider worth answering (only 4 in 2013 compared to >200 in 2011), I hopefully will have forgotten this silly discussion here so that I won't have to consciously disregard it.

So sue me.

Comment: "Since you guys (ha!)" See you in court ;P

Comment: +1 and Thanks for this beautiful answer. It's so nice to hear that you used to work in such a great place. Guess it is the difference in times, due to which I misinterpreted it. Sorry for the same. Thanks again for such a beautiful piece of writing.

Comment: @Infinite: I have no idea what you misinterpreted where, but then I didn't read much of this discussion. I have always tried to work at places like this. My current employer is also _very_ good at maintaining a great social climate. I don't think it's the difference in times, though. It's a difference in how people feel treated. If some good-natured teasing makes people feel bad, there's something (else) wrong with the company.

Comment: Where I work now, the other day the woman who is HR said, after we talked about it over lunch, that it is good that we developers have better machines than the rest of the company, because we need them, and "they" aren't even fully using the cheaper ones they have. If we hooked up their machines to IB (we don't use VC, though), she'd laugh when I'd say it's the first time her machine does something useful. This is all friendly banter, because we value each other, and we know that we do.

Comment: @BoltClock: In what profession will you be there? Judge? My defense? Spectator? Paparazzi?

Comment: I had a comment in reply to BoltClock's [comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267575/how-much-commentary-is-permitted-in-answers#comment71543_267575) , which I deleted after reading your answer.

Answer (score 10):

> How much commentary is permitted in answers?

If you're referring to material that belongs in comments, *none.*  In general, *if it doesn't clarify the post or ask for clarification, it belongs in comments.*  That's true for questions as well.

As to the specific post in question, the [current revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3950606/7) seems fine to me.  The text you removed was relevant to the answer, the use of the term *girls* notwithstanding.

Answer (score 2):

> How much commentary is permitted in answers?

There should be no commentary or fluff of any kind in answers, though [there are exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1073063). I think your edit was good, because it removed unnecesary text.

> what is the appropriate course of action?

Once it is clear that there is a disagreement, no more edits should be done until it has been discussed. This can be done in the comments, chat or with a question in meta. If you use comments, you should delete them once the discussion is over.

That means that your second edit was already not appropiate. You should have stopped and tried to communicate with the user who wrote the answer.

Answer (score -2):

That answer could certainly be made less sexist. The point that needed to be made is that he hooked up some machines to IB which were otherwise doing no useful work (in his opinion).

It was not necessary to associate the concept of "girls" with the concept of "not doing any useful work".

Comment: He didn't associate "the concept of 'girls'", but these particular girls he was talking about. You *don't* know whether they were doing any useful work or not.

Comment: It was not necessary to characterize those computers beyond saying that _the computers_ were doing no useful work. It did not improve the question to indicate who the users of those computers were.

Comment: True, but the fact that it did not improve the question/answer doesn't imply it was sexist.

Comment: No implication was required. The plain meaning of the text, as written, and as interpreted by me, was that the OP chose to use the term "girls" instead of something neutral like "people" because he wished to associate the term "girls" with "people whose machines performed no useful work in the context". I would hope the OP could clarify whether this was his intention, or whether it just came out that way (maybe the only "guy" whose machine performed "no useful work"was out on vacation).

Comment: I would hope people would wait for the OP to clarify, before judging. There are many other possible scenarios, beside the one you've pointed out, where the post doesn't have any sexist connotations. Also, to reach your conclusion implication is required, because the OP didn't say exactly what you are saying here.

Comment: @BartoszKP: unless the OP is a child, he should by now have experience in writing in a manner which does not lead readers to believe he is sexist. One may safely presume that adults do not write in a sexist manner unless they don't mind being read as being sexist.

Comment: I thought also that one may safely presume that adults understand that different people understand subjective terms very differently, and that premature judgement is not a nice thing to do.

Comment: Nobody put the OP in *jail*, @BartoszKP. An editor (rightly, in my opinion) scrubbed an answer of a word that was creating a very strong sense of sexism. And frankly, this isn't a borderline case. The OP may not be *aware* of the implication, I won't guess, but it is absolutely there.

Comment: @BartoszKP: the fact that different people understand subjective terms differently is a reason for the writers to write differently, not a reason for the readers to read differently.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta You all seem to be fond of overstatements and straw man arguments. I didn't say that OP is in *jail*. Nor the OP said that all females are incapable of using computers. The OP may not be aware of the implication, because *it isn't there*. Do you honestly think that when I happen to see some women not very good at a task I'm not allowed to express it? Must I quickly find at least one guy, that's also poor at it, to be relieved and say with solace that I saw *people*? When I see a group of men that can't handle something talking about it seems easier. Now, isn't that sexist? :|

Comment: @BartoszKP: when it is not relevant to the point being made, please _do_ omit the gender of those involved. In fact, omit _everything_ that is not relevant to the point, or it will be presumed by your readers that you feel these things _are_ relevant to your point.

Comment: @JohnSaunders And also the reason to give some slack when interpreting peoples' words. Especially before imposing something as inelegant as sexism on them.

Comment: When you spy a female mention, in a professional setting, professional "boys" in the office, then say that the tools of their trade weren't being used for anything useful, then we'll talk, @BartoszKP.

Comment: @BartoszKP: there is never a reason to turn a blind eye to sexism, racism, etc. It's very simple. In this case, the point was that IB is a useful way of making use of computers which were otherwise not being used "for useful work". Nothing further was required in order to make the point. The fact that there was further characterization strongly suggests that the characterization was being made part of the point. Solution: if that's not what the OP meant, then the characterization should have been removed.

Comment: @JohnSaunders And there is never a reason to turn a blind eye to unfair accusations of sexism, racism, etc. I'm a bit tired, and really don't understand why I got into this kind of discussion on a supposedly *programming* site. Anyway, it's pointless. If you'd manage to convince me though, I could even view your answer as an example of excessive patriarchy - you *obviously imply* (or was it *strongly suggest*?) that "girls" aren't capable of defending themselves. Good night/day ;)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta We're not talking about talking to someone in the office, we are not talking about whether I would say something to someone or not in an imaginary situation, and we're not talking about your assumptions in this matter. Hopefully next time we'll talk you'll learn to make relevant arguments.

Comment: Have a great night, @BartoszKP!

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure why do you assume that you know better than the poster whether these particular machines he writes about really did something useful. Perhaps their users where really a group of marginally non-technical females (as [Veedrac](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1763356/veedrac) correctly [points out in the comments section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267575/how-much-commentary-is-permitted-in-answers?cb=1#comment71614_267575)). Maybe they also were acting very immature, hence the term "girls". I think it's the poster's right to judge, and only he really knows what he's talking about. Thus the initial edit was incorrect, changing the original meaning. The latter was correct, as this information as a whole was irrelevant in terms of the topic in question. However accusing the poster of sexism seems unfair.

As [Infinite Recursion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2982225/infinite-recursion) points out [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267575/how-much-commentary-is-permitted-in-answers/267589#comment71586_267575):

> It means you when you judge something with your brain, you may be incorrect. But if you feel something from your heart, your feelings are never wrong.

I think it should be fair to apply this statement to the poster also. If he perceived these ladies as "girls" that's his right to do so (even if it was incorrect, however you can't possibly know that). If someone sees it as a suggestion that all females look immature next to a computer then it's their own, incorrect, implication.

The OP added few irrelevant chatty-details to his answer (that the machines weren't used to their full extent before, that it was in an office, etc.). Picking on one of these random-looking details and imposing some special meaning to its existence (as opposed to others) doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: It may be the answerers "right" to judge, but it's hardly relevant to the answer. Also, the use of the smiley ("first time their machines did anything useful  **:)**") suggest a loaded message. "Wink wink, we all know computers are not for girls", "Girls can't be real programmers". Whatever. It's just irrelevant. "Some of these machines were pretty over-dimensioned, so in a way they were finally getting some use". There. No sexism, no jokery, just information. Greatness.

Comment: @sehe Well of course if you try hard enough, you will find sexism *everywhere*, I'm not denying that :)

Comment: @sehe Also, all the parts about whether the machines were useful before or not, were over-dimensioned or not, etc. are irrelevant to the answer. So when it comes to adding some random chatty-details it's only your imagination that says that this particular detail is extremely important and implies sexism.

Comment: It's not irrelevant, since it illustrates the untapped computation capacity available in any office environment.

Comment: Consider an alternative, equally "chatty" remark: "we hooked up the girls' computers *even though* they were doing something useful [for once]" -- with the "[..]" part, the last part is extremely condescending, without, it's totally irrelevant. Removing the last part makes the "girls" part irrelevant. In the end it boils down to "the other computers".

Comment: @sehe It is. Only thing that's relevant to the answer is that IB is scalable and that OP has verified that this feature works running it on many machines in parallel.

Comment: @Jongware Same as above. Most of details in this story are irrelevant, you're just focusing on this one to prove sexism.

Comment: Nobody here accuses or proves sexism. We're just here to discuss whether it's appropriate to edit posts to remove _potentially_ sexist references.

Comment: @sehe If it is, then we have a lot of work to do, because *potentially* sexist reference is a very broad, subjective term as I've stated few times :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=girls  :V

Comment: @BartoszKP  Of course it doesn't follow at all that we should remove all (potential) needlessly sexist references.  This was about whether,  in this case,  it was a good idea to remove the reference. I'm glad you noticed to that people are repeating things. Frankly your supposedly humoristic linking to a search for "girls" suggests to me you are trying to derail the topic by stripping it from its context. No one says you can't use words. Well,  not me at least.  Dixerat.

Comment: As I told you earlier, I agree with your view that till we hear the OP, we can't judge. Today, OP replied. You have my +1 now.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Didn't notice, thanks for your input, and for the notification ;)

Answer (score -10):

Personally, after reading through the comments, I found some particularly important/interesting points:

> Really? The simple use of the word "girls" is sexist now?
>
> -Boltclock

---

> @Infinite Recursion: I'm pretty sure the simple act of using a gender word is not inherently sexist (or use of any other description = prejudiced). That being said, it took me more than a few rereads to get that implication given that the only change was a single word, and I have to admit that it is pretty sinister.
>
> -Boltclock

---

> @InfiniteRecursion You should read the whole answer. Context matters. Using “girls” to mean “assistants” is sexist. But the answer related some historical facts where some of the people involved were unmarried women, so “girls” is factual, not sexist, in that context.
>
> -Gilles

---

> @Gilles I am an unmarried woman, so by your definition it would be factual to refer to me as a "girl". I am 65 years old, with a doctorate in computer science, over 30 years working for computer manufacturers, and an inventor on half a dozen US patents. Would you use "boy" to refer to an unmarried man with similar background? If not, that use of "girl" is sexist.
>
> -Patricia Shanahan

---

Right. So basically we have a two things here:

- the OP wants to specify the gender of the people he was mentioning, which is perfectly harmless
- 'girls' can be taken as offensive, as it can be perceived as referring to a combination of age and gender

Here's how I see it: the OP meant to use `girls` in the context of `girls and guys`, not the context of `girls and boys`. The main difference is that the former is used to specify groups by gender, while the former also specifies age.

Now, seeing as that *some people* seem to keep assuming the latter as opposed to giving the benefit of the doubt to the OP, we need a better word. Since the tone of the writing is quite casual, **`ladies`** may be a better term.

---

<strike>note: IMHO, if you give the benefit of the doubt to OP, `girls` seems just fine to me.</strike>

Comment: The problem is that using the same word for children and adults in some group can make people, at least subconsciously, assume immaturity on the part of all members of the targeted group regardless of age.

Comment: Which is why I suggested **`ladies`** as an alternative solution.

Comment: The analog of *guys* is *gals*, not girls.  In formal contexts, *girls* means prepubescent female humans.

Comment: Staff and mods have diamonds ◆, so bold disclaimer is not required. Answers should address the question. Comments are second class citizens, never dedicate an answer to comment on comments :-)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I was suggesting `ladies` as an answer.

Comment: @wallyk I can honestly say I haven't ever heard anyone say `gals` IRL.

Comment: [Gals on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=gals&__=1008284001)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion not including this page, 3 for `gals` as opposed to 2 for `ladies` and 8 for `girls`, including a quote from an answer, `...need to teach the guy (or girl) half the language...`.

Comment: Good, finally you encountered usage of gals IRL

Comment: IDK, the nets isn't what I usually call IRL.

Comment: The comment clearly implies that women (of any age) aren't as proficient on computers as men by condescendingly referring to them as "girls" with a wink.  The context of those two sentences is _intended_ to be demeaning to women using computers.

Comment: @intracept Was it? I didn't take it that way. If you think about it, when you're telling someone a story IRL, you usually try to be as specific as possible. You want them to _imagine_ the entire story ***as if they were there***. I mean, you can certainly choose to take it negatively with a presumption of an implied negative bias, but I see no obvious bias in the text itself; I see only specificity. How you guys are taking this reminds me of [***this***](http://weknowmemes.com/2012/06/what-the-author-meant-vs-what-your-english-teacher-thinks-the-author-meant/).

Comment: @haneefmubarak You clearly haven't worked as a highly technical female in a very male dominated environment.  I read a story about a male with an androgynous sounding name who looking for work but was unable to even get offered an interview.  He made one tiny change to his CV: he added "Mr" in front of his name.  All of a sudden he was getting interviews.  Same skill set, same experience.  Sexism is very common in this industry.

Comment: @intracept certainly. However, I tend to err on the side of giving people the benefit of the doubt. Doing otherwise is simply unkind. Yes, you may feel one way, but someone else may feel another way, and another feel yet a different way, and so on. I'm not saying it doesn't exist in the industry, I'm simply saying that censoring people for telling a story in the most descriptive way possible is ***unfair censorship***, not _reduction of discrimination_. When there is a ***fair possibility*** that what someone has said could be taken in a non-negative manner, that's how one should take it.

Comment: @haneefmubarak I agree with you - when that is the case.  But those two sentences with that condescending smiley have one meaning and one meaning only and no amount of trying to rationalise the use of the word "girls" _in that context_ will convince me (and probably most other technical women) otherwise.  It was unjustified and _intentionally_ offensive, a nod to the boys on Stack Overflow about those silly women, you know how they are!

Comment: I don't believe so. To me, it just seems like a friendly smile. I've often interjected 'friendly smiles' into my conversations; it isn't necessarily condescending. Especially in chat... but I digress. The point is that that too, the smiley, could plausibly be innocent. As for _intent_, well, as my mother has always said, `If you aren't a person, you cannot know what they are thinking. Only [a] god can do that`. It honestly could have just been part of the storytelling. However, I _do_ think that the OP would have been fine with someone removing their _smiley_ as opposed to their ***words***.

Comment: @Infinite Recursion: By the way, I haven't had the opportunity to thank you for your clarification since my last comment on the question. So thanks :)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion The sad thing is (which I know we've touched on before on a different thread) is that the sexism in this industry forces most of us to use androgynous user names (such as I was using and as you do) to avoid it.  It frustrates me that we have to hide. :(

Comment: I am inspired by potatoes, unicorns, smurfs and lizard profiles :) As for being androgynous, I go around telling everyone on Meta that I am a she...hardly makes sense if someone is trying to hide due to sexism. @JaneS

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion True :)  And I have a picture of myself in my profile, so I countered my own argument!  So there! :)

Comment: Along the lines of closing this up, I'd like to thank @JaneS for actually being willing to discuss the topic. While in the end we both still appear to have a difference of opinion (which is perfectly fine), at least we both had the opportunity to voice our concerns and be heard. Thanks!